# Why is there two types of Puppet 'Exec' and Puppet 'exec'

Tags: puppet

This is going to be a Noob question.

Why are there two types of Exec in Puppet, Exec and exec. I cannot find the difference between the two.

```
Exec {
    path => ["/usr/bin", "/bin", "/usr/sbin", "/sbin", "/usr/local/bin","/usr/local/sbin"]
}

#execute the following command
exec { 

     #this is our command name
    'apt-get update':

    #the command to be executed
    command => '/usr/bin/apt-get update',

    #where we can find the required command
    require => Exec['add php54 apt-repo']
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code you can see three different usages of the keyword exec:

The first one

```
Exec {
    path => ["/usr/bin", "/bin", "/usr/sbin", "/sbin", "/usr/local/bin","/usr/local/sbin"]
}
```

changes the default value for the attribute path of the resource Exec.

The second one:

```
#execute the following command
exec { 

     #this is our command name
    'apt-get update':
```

creates a instance of the resource

The third one:

```
require => Exec['add php54 apt-repo']
```

refers to a existing instance using his name ('add php54 apt-repo')

Answer (score 2):

There is only one resurce type, when used capitalized you're doing a resource reference [1] which affect all resources of that type within the applicable scope.

[1] http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3/reference/lang_resources.html#amending-attributes-with-a-reference